# Gradle context sensitive support in STS/Eclipse

Tags: gradle, spring-tool-suite

I am trying to evaluate Gradle as next-gen build tool for some of my future projects.

Steps I've done so far:

1. I have Java 7 installed on my machine.
2. Installed Gradle 2.0
3. Installed Spring Tool Suite 3.6.1, went to dashboard and added support for 
   Gradle and installed also Groovy-Eclipse package.

Now when I start Gradle projects from scratch or I clone some of the projects from github,
I am not able to get context sensitive help, like Ctrl + Space to autocomplete stuff in
build.gradle file.

I was reading a lot of documentation on net about this, and couldn't find proper answer, so if someone can give me some idea is it working?

Previously I was using Maven, and m2-eclipse, so when I type in pom.xml I am able to do Ctrl + Space which prevents me to make typo mistakes.

NOTE: Just please note that I've enabled Gradle DSL support for my Gradle projects.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle's build language is much more dynamic, extensible, and powerful than a Maven POM, and hence it's much harder to develop full IDE support for it. Recent versions of the [Eclipse Gradle Plugin](https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-gradle) have limited editing support, and work is underway to take it to the next level. IntelliJ 14 is already further along, but expect to see further improvements there as well.

Comment: I've checked IntelliJIdea 13, community edition. It has some context help but it is still not the way I used to work with Maven. So how do you prevent typo errors, that may occur in build.gradle, specially on startup the project?

Comment: 14 is another step up from 13. Not sure what you are looking for in particular.

Comment: Ok, maybe I wasn't too specific.  So for example, if I am going to add section dependencies, and I start to type comp, and then I do Ctrl + Space, I should get context sensitive help like: compile, or if I type testC, and then do same, Ctrl + Space, I should get offer testCompile. This type of help I think it would be helpfull.

Comment: This type of help is already available for IntelliJ, but not yet for Eclipse.